# Java Has-A relationship, composition or aggregation

Tags: java, associations

I searched on google and i got more confused than before.
Is Has-A relationship both composition and agregation?
Or is it only aggregation, so composition is like "Part-Of"?
Or we just say Object "has-a" Other Object meaning that the relationship can be composition or aggregation.
Can you explain the differences between aggregation  and composition?

This code

```
public class Tree{
     private Leaf leaf =  new Leaf();
}
```

is  different from

```
public class Tree{
    private Leaf leaf;
    public Tree(Leaf leaf){
       this.leaf = leaf;
    }
}
```

so, im sure the first is Composition because leaf exist only if Tree is created. But with the second example the tree maybe has a leaf reference from an "outside" list and if i delete the (second example) tree, the leaf still exists.

So we can say that:

- **Composition is**: when a Container(tree) object is "deleted" the contained(leaf) is "deleted" too
- **Aggregation is**: When a Container(second tree) object is "deleted" the contained(leaf) is not "deleted"

Is this right?

Comment: Whether a relationship is composition or aggregation depends on the circumstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Clear one Thing
Both composition and aggregation comes under the umbrella of association. Means both composition and aggregation are two types of association.

When there is a weak association then this aggregation, or when there is no part whole relationship means child can exists independent of parent. Example of Association is Employee and Bank. A person can be employee of any of the bank, or can change the bank. Or the bank can exists without the employee.

When there is a strong association then this is composition, or when there is a part whole relationship means child cannot exists without parent. Example of Composition is Human and its heart. Heart cannot exists independently without human and human cannot exists independently without heart. "**Has a**" keyword only exists with composition because In composition one contain object of other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
That's perfect,  i got everything but i have 1 more doubt now, Human has-a heart, but Animal has-a heart too. The Association is a relationship between classes or object? Can  i use Heart in both Animal and Human saying it is composition?
Tysm

Comment: Again in what ever mode you are working. Heart doesn't have it's independent existence. It is always contained inside human, animal or etc. So you can't make Objects of Heart and just pass it onto human or animal in the constructor. Hear Object must be made inside the Human or animal class. Don't get confused just think of part whole relationship whenever you are making relationship between classes